Why my Logistic regression has 25% accuracy?
I am implementing Logistic regression. I know there are already lots of libraries to implement it. But the thing is I am not able to understand with those. So I created my Own dataset for it.
It has 3 things, House Price, Standard and Buying Decision
Standard represents living standard.
0 : low
1 : medium
2 : high
When house price is very low, only people with low(0) living standrads will buy.
When house high is very high, only people with high(2) living standrads will buy.
Here is what I did
# %%
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import pandas
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# %%
house_buy = pandas.read_csv("Datasets/house.csv")
house_buy

# %%
house_test = pandas.read_csv("Datasets/house test.csv")
house_test.head()

# %%
house_independent = house_buy.iloc[:,:-1]
house_dependent = house_buy["Buy Prediction"]

# %%
column_names = house_independent.columns.tolist()
column_names

# %%
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_house_independent = pandas.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(house_independent), columns=column_names)
scaled_house_independent.head()

# %%
house_dependent.shape

# %%
house_test_independent = house_test.iloc[:,:2]
house_test_dependent = house_test["Buy Prediction"]
house_test_independent, house_test_dependent

# %%
# Scaled house test
scaled_house_test_independent = pandas.DataFrame(scaler.transform(house_test_independent), columns=column_names)
scaled_house_test_independent

# %%
house_regression_model = LogisticRegression(random_state=42).fit(scaled_house_independent, house_dependent)

# %%
#Test
house_predicted_dependent = house_regression_model.predict(scaled_house_test_independent)
house_predicted_dependent

# %%
accuracy = accuracy_score(house_test_dependent,house_predicted_dependent)
accuracy

# %%

Here is dataset and ipynb file of my implementation
The test dataset has array(1,1,0,0) as buying decision but my model gives array(0,1,1,1)
I know my dataset is small, but that must not be the only reason for such a low accuracy.
What am I doing wrong? How to perform it?

Please notice that SO does not work by linking to code in an external repo; see how to create a [mre].

4 samples is quite small to get an reliable estimate for the accuracy. You should also check your accuracy on your test set if it has reasonable values. Is that set also very small? Then that would explain it.

@Darran Yes the train dataset is also small. It has 16 entries. I manually created the dataset for more understanding of the regression model.

Then I have tried on another dataset which is large. It is about  weather a person will take a loan or not. depending on city, age, marital status and many mode fields.
i first standardised the train data, and then on same scaler i standardised the test data seperately, i heard this avoid data leakage. The accuracy was 0.87. But I am not able to improve it, no matter whichever hyperperameter I use, 0.87 remains as it is.
Is this because of regression model or am I doing something wrong??
